# HTML -webkit-animation / animation

Tags: html, css, css-animations

I found some prewritten code and wonder what the difference is between -webkit-animation and animation. Both are used at the same place in a css file to animate some background. These articles about [animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/animation) and [-webkit-animation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media/-webkit-animation) gave me some inside, but I could not find an answer. The code-snippet looks as follows:

```
  animation: slideright 600s infinite linear;
  -webkit-animation: slideright 600s infinite linear;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is that code using `-webkit-animation` is code witten before `animation` was standardised. Since animation has been widely supported for several years, you can now remove all references to `-webkit-animation` and just stick with `animation`.

The only exception would be if, looking at the two MDN pages you link, you decide that you wish to support very old Safari versions that handle -webkit-animation but not -animation.